# function that return the percentage of blanks and nulls of a table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I need a function e.g. (analysis_1) with 2 argument, a table and an array of columns of this table.

The aim of this function is to return another table like this:

`analysis_1(table1, ArrayofColumns)`

| Name of the column | Percentage of Null | Percentage of Blank | Data formats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Col1 | % | % | Date |
| Col2 | % | % | float |
| Col3 | % | % | float |
| Col4 | % | % | character |

For example, I've a table like this:

Name of the table: Names_imports

| Id | Name | City | Import | Debts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luigi | Rome | 4.56 | null |
| 2 | Jean Pierre | Paris |  | 3.25 |
| 3 | Carlos | Mexico | 10 | 4 |
| 4 | Boris | Berlin | null | 35.42 |

`analysis_1(Names_imports, c("Name","City","Import","Debts"))`

Therefore, the return of the function should be like this:

| Name_column | %Null | %Blank | Dataformats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | 0 | 0 | character |
| City | 0 | 0 | character |
| Import | 0.25 | 0.25 | float |
| Debts | 0.25 | 0 | float |

I use this to calculate the rows of the return table, but **I don't know how to transpose it in a table.**

```
(colSums(is.na(Names_imports))/nrow(Names_imports))*100
(colSums(is.na(Names_imports))/nrow(Names_imports))*100
```

I know that I should use data.table, can you give any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with base `R`, but since you are looking for a `data.table` solution, you can try this. Also, I assume you mean the `NA` rate within a column and not the `NULL` rate within a column so that is what I've created. I created a function called `analysis_1` which takes the data you provide and a vector of column names. I return the names, `NA` rate, blank rate, and column types from this. I set it up so that if you don't pass any columns, it will use all of them.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(x = sample(c(NA, 1:5), size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
                 y = sample(c(NA, c("pizza", "dog", "", "")), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                 z = sample(c(NA, c("a", "b", "c", "", "")), size = 10, replace = TRUE))

dt
#>      x     y    z
#>  1: NA  <NA>     
#>  2:  3           
#>  3: NA           
#>  4:  1 pizza    a
#>  5:  4 pizza    a
#>  6:  2  <NA>     
#>  7:  5       <NA>
#>  8:  1          c
#>  9:  2  <NA> <NA>
#> 10:  2  <NA>    c

analysis_1 <- function(df, ArrayofColumns = names(df)){
  # select only certain columns
  dt_select <- df[, ArrayofColumns, with = FALSE]
  
  # compute the different metrics
  missing_rate <- colMeans(is.na(dt_select))
  dataformats <- lapply(dt_select, class)
  blank_rate <- lapply(dt_select, function(m) sum(as.character(m) == "", na.rm = TRUE) / nrow(dt_select))
  
  dt_out <- data.table(Name_column = names(dt_select), 
                       `%NA` = missing_rate, 
                       `%Blank` = blank_rate,
                       Dataformats = dataformats)
  dt_out
  
}

analysis_1(dt, c("x", "z"))
#>    Name_column %NA %Blank Dataformats
#> 1:           x 0.2      0     integer
#> 2:           z 0.2    0.4   character
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. I had a problem in `function(m) sum(m == "", na.rm = TRUE)` when m is a Date but I solved it with `function(m) sum(**as.character**(m) == "", na.rm = TRUE)`. I think it will work!

Comment: Thanks. I have made an adjustment to the answer. However, I am not sure how a date object can take on a value other than a date or an `NA`. So a date taking on a value of `""` seems surprising to me.